# How to create the exact number of textview and put them in to tableview?

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, tablelayout

I have this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textview;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    String hallo = "blabla " + "jojo " + "lol " + "\n" + "doj " + "drasl " + "\n"; 
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(hallo.getBytes());
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] RowData = line.split(" ");
            String eitt = RowData[0];
            String tvo = RowData[1];

            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(line);

            linearLayout.addView(textView);
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

with this xml layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I want to insert these parts of a string into a table layout, so that when my pieces of text are printed they come out in nice columns. The way this works, it just prints the string line for line instead of putting it into columns. It's also very important to know that I don't know how many lines are going to be in the string, so I can't just make 4 textview boxes because there could be 50 og a hundred lines, so I need to make an i amount of textview boxes in a table view with i being the number of lines

Answer (score 2):

Try by adding `setLayoutParams` to `TextView` :

```
//Your code...
String line;
    try {
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] RowData = line.split(" ");
            String eitt = RowData[0];
            String tvo = RowData[1];

            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(line);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT
           ,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            linearLayout.addView(textView);
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

//Your code...
```

Comment: I tried this, but i got the error, call requires API level 11. I am using API 10. This error is for FILL_PARENT, do you know what i can do about that ?

Comment: then you can use other LayoutParams options LayoutParams.wrap_content or LayoutParams.fill_parent

Comment: I tried to use wrap_content,fill_parent, match_parent, everything gives me the samt error. Did i have to change something in the xml file ?